# Can Angular 4 module work with Angular 2 project

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have a module that I updated to Angular 4 and I have an Angular 2 project that uses this module.
Is there a way my Angular 2 project will use the module without updating to Angular 4?

**Update**
I'm using ionic and when i run `ionic serve` I'm getting the following errors:
[ionic serve errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fVPw.jpg)
'priority-ionic' is my angular4 module and i run `ionic serve` on the angular2 project.

Comment: Yes it should work

Answer (score 1):

It will work since there is no change between angular 2 and angular 4.
Changing from version 2 to version 4, 5, … won’t be like changing from Angular 1. The below things are only changed in angular aka angular 4.

1. Enhanced *ngIf syntax

   Loading...

   {{ user.name }}
2. Animation Package
3. StrictNullChecks
4. Universal
5. Flat ES Modules (Flat ESM / FESM) <-- this can be taken as just an upgrade but there is no such change which will stop the previous angular modules from working.
6. ES2015 Builds(Experimental)

You may refer to the docs [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)